# How can I create a Date Range from a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a database that has these params:

```
Transaction Date, User Email Address
```

The resultant table I want is these params:

```
Email Address, dateDiff
```

For dateDiff, I want to find the difference between the earliest transaction date and latest transaction date.

How would I go about doing this?

My code (clearly not correct)

```
SELECT [Email Address], DATEDIFF(day, [Transaction Date],[Transaction Date]) AS 'dateDiff'
FROM [DB].[TABLE]
ORDER BY [dateDiff] Desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an aggregation to get the minimum and maximum values for each email, before doing `datediff()`:

```
SELECT [Email Address],
       DATEDIFF(day, min([Transaction Date]), max([Transaction Date])) AS 'dateDiff'
FROM [DB].[TABLE]
GROUP BY [Email Address]
order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: Thanks! Could I also get the count of each e-mail by adding  COUNT(*) AS 'count', in the SELECT, or would I need to change the GROUP BY as well?

Comment: Yes, you can add additional columns such as `count(*)` as well.